# Use of the word 'alls'

Tags: meaning-in-context, colloquialisms

This is my first question here. My specific doubt does not seem to have been already answered, so here I am!

My questions are:

• What is the word 'alls', morphologically speaking?

• Would you be able to point its standard use, if there is any?

• Is the following sentence grammatical and/or acceptable? Is it a colloquialism?

"[...] they counterbalance acid and bitter flavors, thus making his recipe **alls** more enjoyable and adaptive to the tastes of every person."

Thank you in advance. Cheers!

Comment: I'm trying to think of any context at all where the word "alls" (with no apostrophe) would be appropriate.  Can you give any example you've found in your reading?

Comment: I have written an example between quotation marks just after the bullet points ;)

Comment: For dialectal "Alls I want to say, is that ...", meaning "All I want to say is that  ..." and comparing "Something I want to say is that ...", "alls" looks to be a contraction of "all is". (I don't find your example with "alls" to be acceptable.)

Comment: Oh, here I found a news article on it: http://www.nytimes.com/2010/09/12/magazine/12onlanguage.html

Comment: So you say that the writer theirselves did not use it "properly"?

Comment: Repeat: alls is a spoken form from uneducated speakers, mostly used like this: Alls I want to say is, Alls he means is. It is almost always at the beginning  of spoken utterances, and never written down, except maybe in a dialogue in a movie script.  it's like: gonna, wanna, shoulda. etc.

Comment: OK< I think your text has a TYPO: " thus making his recipe alls more " should be:  "thus making his recipe all the more enjoyable". RIGHT. It is typos.

Comment: Note that "all's" (with the apostrophe) is a contraction of "all is", as in "All's well that ends well."

Comment: You are right to doubt it - "alls" doesn't work in the example you quote.

Comment: "Doubts" cannot be answered. You mean "question". Otherwise people will think you have insecurity issues. :)

Answer (score 1):

The *alls*-construction is part of the dialects of Midwestern American English. It refers to the appearance of *-s* on the word *all*. It is also sometimes spelled with an apostrophe before the *-s*.

There has been some discussion on linguistlist.org about the possibility that the *-s* may be a reduced form or *is* or *as*. Some have also pointed out other potentially related cases where an *-s* suffix appears in spoken English, such as *Hows about we leave soon?* or *That's a long ways away from here*.

As for the use of *alls*, the *-s* suffix characteristic of the *alls*-construction has a restricted distribution, and cannot always appear on *all*. For example, *-s* would not appear on phrases such as *all or nothing*. The *-s* also cannot appear on all in inverted sentences (sentences in which the verb precedes the subject) or ordinary (or free) relative clauses (clauses starting with *who*, *that*, *which*, *whose*, *where*, and *when*). Some speakers of the dialects of which *alls* is characteristic of also reportedly do not allow the *alls*-construction with second person subjects.

The sentence you provided is not one of the characteristic uses of *alls* as it has been described. It seems to resemble phrases like *all the more enjoyable*. It is possible that it is a genuine construction/colloquialism for some speakers, but if so, it hasn’t been described in the linguistics literature, as far as we know.

Here’s a page we’ve written on the alls construction: https://ygdp.yale.edu/phenomena/alls-construction